# Data Table Solution in R To Trim

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

```
dataHAVE=data.frame("student"=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),
                    "time"=c(1:4,1:4,1:4),
                    "score"=c(NA,0,NA,NA,0,1,1,1,0,0,NA,NA),
                    "class"=c('A','A','B','B','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','B'))


library(dplyr)
dataWANT2 <- group_by(dataHAVE,student) %>% 
  slice(seq_len(min(which(score == 1), n()))) %>% 
  filter(class != "B")
```

I come up with a dplyr solution to my problem which is to do this:

if score = 1, delete all rows that follow for that student but keep the first row that equals to 1.

if class = 'B' delete that row and all others that come after it for that student.

I am searching for a data.tale solution to this.

Comment: student 1 has a row with class == 'B', but this dplyr code doesn't delete all student 1 rows (same applies to student 3). So your description doesn't match the output of the dplyr code. Which output are you expecting, the one you describe or the dplyr output?

Comment: @IceCreamToucan i do not wish to delete all student 1 rows--just the student 1 rows with a B. I apologize if description is not clear as I am an English learner. Ideally the data.table solution matches dataWANT2. Thank you a bunch.

Comment: Ok, in that case it seems this part " and all others for that student." should be deleted from the questoin.

Comment: @IceCreamToucan I updated the question content thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to do:

```
setDT(dataHAVE)

# fill na, cumsum doesn't accept NA values
dataHAVE[, score := replace(score, is.na(score), 0)]

dataHAVE[class != 'B', cumscore := cumsum(score), student]
dataHAVE <- dataHAVE[class != 'B' & cumscore <= 1]
dataHAVE[,  cumscore := NULL]
print(dataHAVE)

   student time score class
1:       1    1     0     A
2:       1    2     0     A
3:       2    1     0     A
4:       2    2     1     A
5:       3    1     0     A
6:       3    2     0     A
7:       3    3     0     A
```

Answer (score 3):

In data.table, `.I` is a vector of row numbers, so this creates a column which, for each group, is the subset of the row numbers to keep. Since I didn't name this variable, it is created with the default name `V1`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dataHAVE)

i <- 
  dataHAVE[, .I[!(cumsum(fcoalesce(shift(score == 1), FALSE) + (class == 'B')))],
           by = student]$V1

dataHAVE[i]
#    student time score class
# 1:       1    1    NA     A
# 2:       1    2     0     A
# 3:       2    1     0     A
# 4:       2    2     1     A
# 5:       3    1     0     A
# 6:       3    2     0     A
# 7:       3    3    NA     A
```

Broken into two steps above for clarity, but you don't have to create the `i` variable. This will give the same output.

```
dataHAVE[dataHAVE[, .I[!(cumsum(fcoalesce(shift(score == 1), FALSE) + (class == 'B')))],
         by = student]$V1]
```

Comment: thank you so much what is significance of .I and $V1? i wonder is there a direct way to create the new dataset?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the dplyr code correctly, you are keeping rows from start until the first occurrence of score == 1 and if no score == 1, keep all rows. Here is another `data.table` option:

```
setDT(dataHAVE)
dataHAVE[score==1L, ri := rowid(student, score)]
dataHAVE[class!="B" & (is.na(ri) | ri < 2L)]
```

output:

```
   student time score class ri
1:       1    1    NA     A NA
2:       1    2     0     A NA
3:       2    1     0     A NA
4:       2    2     1     A  1
5:       3    1     0     A NA
6:       3    2     0     A NA
7:       3    3    NA     A NA
```